# Autocomplete that only accept the listed options using materialize

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, materialize, typescript

Because I was unable to enter text in a Select widget, I am using an Autocomplete Input widget. My question is how only to accept options that the autocomplete list suggest?

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="SimpleInput" class="autocomplete validate" required>
          <label for="SimpleInput">AutocompleteSimple</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER -->
```

Javascript

```
var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, 
  {data: 
     {"Apple": null,
    "Microsoft": null,
    "Google": null},
    minLength: 0});
```

**Expectation**

I expect this Autocomplete widget only to accept inputs which are in the option and possibly if feasible add additional self-made input options. In other cases, the widget should be red, like in the case when no input is added. In other words, these inputs should be considered invalid.

**Actual result**
It accepts all kind of inputs.

The code which I use can also be seen in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tsai_94/pen/xoEZEY)

Comment: Just don't do anything with the input until they've actually selected a suggestion

Comment: Your comment seems feasible, but before I accept your answer as a solution, I need to ensure that it is possible to invalidate self-made options (unknown options). It may take some time, but I think the following [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) may help me validate your suggestion.

Comment: I didnt give you an answer I gave you a suggestion. And when you say *invalidate self-made options* do you really mean validate? Validation is arbitrary, its up to you to decide if something is valid or not. Why wouldn't you be able to check the selected value and run it against your own validation logic? What makes you think that would be a problem?

Comment: I intended to say to invalid an input (self-made options) if it is not among the different options. Yes, that is what I am trying to do, but as I have little experience I have not decided/determined if this is a suggestion that I would recommend following and consequently accept as my solution.